# aws sns push notification Creating a platform endpoint from Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS for push notification using FCM. Push notification Implementation is working fine. Is there any tutorial on how to create platform endpoint from kotlin mobile side?. Or is it supposed to do it from server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreatePlatformEndpoint` would typically be called from your server as opposed to directly from the mobile device.

This is generally recommended as it helps you avoid having to distribute AWS credentials to make these SDK calls to all of your users.